# Remaining Work rollup issue

Tags: vsts

On Visual Studio Team System (VSTS), I understand that Remaining Work (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork) should automatically roll up from tasks to PBIs (Product Backlog Items)/Bugs (of course if they're linked through Parent/Child link type). I created a new Process (from modified Scrum process), new project and assigned my new process to the new project I had created. So far so good.

When I create tasks either under a PBI or a Bug, the Remaining Work I enter in these tasks doesn't roll up to their parents (PBIs/Bugs). I compared the new template to an existing one (the existing one actually rolls everything up properly) and couldn't find any differences as far as this field (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork) is concerned. Is there an additional setting that I need to check somewhere for the Roll-up to start happening?

I have Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork field defined in PBI, Bug and Task templates and all of them have Formula = 'sum'.

Below is the screengrab of the field's definition which is exactly the same for all 3 work item types (PBI/Bug/Task)

[image]

Comment: You could also try this maybe it gives you what you are looking for:
https://github.com/OliverDolan/vstso

Answer (score 1):

It does not roll up directly to data fields on the parent work item. Instead many of the Agile Planning Tool views show the roll up on a virtual field.

[image]

You can see ob the Backlog Item that the Remaining work has been rolled up for you. There are other views in relation to sprints where this happens.

If however you want to sum the work up you can, for TFS use the built in Data Warehouse to do the sum in a report, or in VSTS you can use the PowerBI Adapter for the same purpose.

Comment: Hi MrHinsh, yes you're right. It doesn't aggregate on the backlog board, but it does on the sprint board. Pretty weird why they do it this way, but it'll work.

Comment: I want it to aggregate on the Sprint Backlog, but there is no value on the Product Backlog. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'd like to be able to aggregate on the product backlog too. But it's not a big deal.

Comment: You can request it on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com